# Rust Option enum best practice in scenario that a struct has its own one time off initialiser

Tags: rust

To make the question more clear, i am trying to find a better way for the below task, say i have a `Config` struct which will be initialised with the config values provided by user, but all the configs are optional, in the case that user didn't provide a value, then it will be initialised with some default values.

```rust
pub struct Config {
  pub a: Option<u128>,
  pub b: Option<Duration>
  // ...
}

impl Config {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    // ...
    Self {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

My confusion is that even i know for sure that each field of the `Config` instance i get from the `Config::new()` function has a solid value `Some(x)`, but still in the later program everywhere when i need a value from this config instance, i need to call `unwrap`, is there a better way to avoid these ubiquitous `unwrap`？

Or is there a better design i should go with?

I am still learning rust, sorry if it is some stupid questions.

Comment: If you use the `serde` crate (which would be a good choice) for configuration parsing, consider using its `default` field attribute instead of Options, see https://serde.rs/attr-default.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In general: One way to go is to have two structs. One with all things Options, and another with all of them plain values, and a function to create an Option of the latter from the former.

```
struct ConfigPre {
  pub a: Option<u128>,
  pub b: Option<Duration>,
}
struct Config {
  pub a: u128,
  pub b: Duration,
}

impl Config {
  fn new(from: ConfigPre) -> Option<Self> {
    Some(Self { a: from.a?, b: from.b? })
  }
}
```

This is tedious to type out, and you can take it one step further by using builders and have this code + some convenience setters autogenerated. Try e.g. [typed-builder](https://docs.rs/typed-builder/0.9.1/typed_builder/derive.TypedBuilder.html).

In your specific case: If you set all the values of `Config` to `Some` in `new`, why do they need to be `Options` in the first place?

Comment: sorry i miss one piece of info, the `Config` struct is used with `envy::from_env` and `serde_json::from_str`, if i don't set them as `Option<a>` then user must provide one value for it, or else the parse will fail.

Comment: the duplicated structs way i did think about it for 1 sec, not the approach at all, could u help to build a simple example to demonstrate how the typed builder can help to avoid those ubiquitous `unwrap`?

Comment: If you don't know in advance whether the values are provided or not, there's no way to remove `unwrap`s. If there's any sensible defaults for them, well, just use `serde::default` and drop the `Option`s.

Comment: typed-builder won't play well with serde. I assumed you construct those structs in code manually.